# Moving files within a Terminal server from a user's roaming folder to a file server path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the script below to move and replace an existing file. It works and it has been tested.

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\test1" | Rename-Item -NewName "test2"
Copy-Item C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\test1 -Destination C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local -Recurse
```

Now, my problem is I want to apply this to remote terminal environment, where there is a FileServer A holds the user's current local data and there is a roaming folder I need to move data from on a specific terminal say TS01.

I want to accomplish the following:

```
Get-Item -Path "FILESERVER\USERNAME\AppData\local\test1" | Rename-Item -NewName "test2" # this renames the file
Copy-Item HOSTNAME\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\test1 -Destination C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local -Recurse # this copies the "test1" folder onto the destination**
```

How do I get a prompt window showing me the current usernames on that FILESERVER path?

What can I use to call the hostname on my path?

Comment: Windows network paths start with double backslashes, I can't see that in your code.

Comment: Windows networking uses `\\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME`.  Perhaps somethin like `\\FILESERVER\C$\Users\joebob\AppData\Roaming\test1`.